# Printing a String array in the order given by an int array

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an int array with random numbers. and I have a string array already filled as well.
I'm trying to display (`System.out.print`) the `String` array in an order corresponding to the order within the `int` array.

like, if the `int array[]={3,1,2}`, and if the inital `String array[]={"a","b","c"}`, then I'd like the string array to print as

```
stringArray[intArray]={c, a, b}
```

in this example, `"a"` at index 0 would correspond to number 1, etc.

I wondered if I could do something like (I tried, but I got an "out of bound" exception, so I guess it's still possible) :

```
for (int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++) {
    if(intArray[i] != 0) {
        System.out.println( stringArray[ intArray[i] ] );
    }
}
```

I also tried to set the length of the loop as length-1, without success.

Please note that I'm trying to make it work in a basic way, without objects or methods. I've read something about a `TreeMap`, but that's already way too advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that array indexes start with **zero**, try to decrement the value retrieved from the int array.

```
for (int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++) {
        if(intArray[i] != 0) {
            System.out.println( stringArray[ intArray[i]-1 ] );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your loop is fine, but you must ensure that the int array has int values in the [0..stringArray) range. That is, if your stringArray has size 5, the valid random numbers are in the closed interval [0,1,2,3,4]